# $\Omega^*$ and $T^*$

Tags: differential-topology

Let $\Omega^*$ be the algebra generated by $dx_1,\dots,dx_n$ subject to the relations $(dx_i)^2=0$ and antisymmetry.

Does this form the cotangent space $T^*$?

I thought it might, since the tangent space $T$ has basis $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1},\dots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\right\}$

But I wasn't sure how to see that $dx_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}=1$ (assuming this behaves like a traditional dual space.)

---

Context: Bott and Tu says that the exterior differentiation $d$ gives us $d(0-\!\text{forms})=\text{gradient}$, and normally we write (for $3$-dim space say) $$Df=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\dots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)$$

Where here the exterior differentiation gives us:
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx+ \dots + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} dz$$

Which in the basis $\{dx,dy,dz\}$ is the same, where I thought that this was the basis of a cotangent space perhaps.

Comment: The relation $dx_i^2 = 0$ is a consequence of antisymmetry. Also, are you asking about the (co)tangent space to a smooth manifold at some fixed point?

Comment: @Travis I suppose so, but I'm so unsure that I wasn't able to specify further. I had done a physics course that weakly touched these things, and now I am looking at Bott and Tu, trying to fix them together

Comment: As for showing that $dx_1\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\right) = 1$, this depends on your definitions of those objects.